# javaFX. How to set auto fill built-in module?

Tags: javafx

So, I have main frame start.fxml and opinion.fxml.
start.fxml - have "Button" item, and empty "AncorPane".

When I click on Button, in "StartController.java" execute:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane ancorPaneMainFrame;

....

public void StatisticOpinion() {
    try {
        Node node = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/StatisticsPackage/Opinion/opinion.fxml"));
        ancorPaneMainFrame.getChildren().setAll(node);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // logging ioe
    }
}
```

That script is place opinion.fxml in AncorPane of start.fxml.

So, now I have problem with auto-resize opinion.fxml when I change size of start.fxml by mouse while programm is working.

opinion.fxml is not fill-out of parent AncorPane...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `AnchorPane` is properly resized and `node` is resizeable you simply have to set the anchors:

```
Node node = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/StatisticsPackage/Opinion/opinion.fxml"));

// set anchors
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(node, 0d);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(node, 0d);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(node, 0d);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(node, 0d);

ancorPaneMainFrame.getChildren().setAll(node);
```